# In AS3 how would i add 2 buttons that would enable the player to move on press instead of using the arrow keys?

Tags: actionscript-3

I got this code off the internet for the game Pong to work on my AS3 document for my assignment. However i'm pretty much a beginner at code and i'm trying to get this game to work on mobile as the assignment needs a game to work on it. 
Because it uses arrow keys, i would like to basically just replace them with buttons instead, one for going up and one for going down. I just don't know the type of code that would allow me to do that.
Something like, when button is pressed, player moves up or down depending which button, but im not sure where to replace the code and what to get rid of.

Here's the "Pong" class file:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Pong extends MovieClip {
        //constants

        private var pongUp:MovieClip = new PongUp  ;

        private var pongDown:MovieClip = new PongDown  ;

        const ballspeed:int = 10;
        const playerspeed:int = 7;
        const computerspeed:int = 10;
        const computerIntelligence:int = 7;//intelligence is 7 out of 10

        //global variables
        var vx:int =  -  ballspeed;// x component of velocity of ball (velocity is speed with direction)
        var vy:int = ballspeed;// y component of velocity of ball
        var v1:int = 0;// initial velocity of player
        var v2:int = 0;// initial velocity of computer
        var playerScore:int = 0;
        var computerScore:int = 0;

        var player:MovieClip = new PongPlayer  ;
        var computer:MovieClip = new PongComputer  ;
        var ball:MovieClip = new PongBall  ;

        public function Pong() {
            //init();       
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        }
        //this function will add all event listeners
        function init(e:Event):void {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,KeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EnterFrame);

            addChild(player);
            addChild(computer);
            addChild(ball);

            player.x = 23;
            player.y = 300;

            computer.x = 637;
            computer.y = 311;

            ball.x = 308;
            ball.y = 328;

            addChild(pongUp);

            pongUp.x = 25;
            pongUp.y = 700;

            addChild(pongDown);

            pongDown.x = 530;
            pongDown.y = 700;


        }
        // this function resets the game
        function reset():void {
            player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            computer.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            ball.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            ball.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            if (Math.abs(Math.random() * 2) > 1)
            {
                vx =  -  ballspeed;
            }
            else
            {
                vx = ballspeed;
            }
            if (Math.abs(Math.random() * 2) > 1)
            {
                vy =  -  ballspeed;
            }
            else
            {
                vy = ballspeed;
            }
        }


        //pongDown.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,moveDown );

        //function moveDown ( e:MouseEvent ): void

        //{





        //}     
        //this function sets the velocity of player when key is pressed  
        function KeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                v1 =  -  playerspeed;
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                v1 = playerspeed;
            }
        }
        //this function sets the velocity of player to 0 if key is released 
        function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                v1 = 0;
            }
        }

        //This function is executed when a frame changes
        function EnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            //variable decleration
            var pHalfHeight = player.height / 2;// half height of player(used for collisions)
            var pHalfWidth = player.width / 2;// half width of player (used for collisions)
            var bHalfHeight = ball.height / 2;// half height of ball(used for collisions)
            var bHalfWidth = ball.width / 2;// half width of ball (used for collisions)

            //moving the player
            player.y +=  v1;
            //limiting the motion of player (it should not move beyond the stageheight)
            if (player.y + pHalfHeight > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                player.y = stage.stageHeight - pHalfHeight;
            }
            else if (player.y - pHalfHeight < 0)
            {
                player.y = 0 + pHalfHeight;
            }

            //moving the ball
            ball.x +=  vx;
            ball.y +=  vy;

            //moving the computer automatically
            if (Math.abs(Math.random() * 10) < computerIntelligence)
            {
                var d:int = computer.y - ball.y;
                if (Math.abs(d) > pHalfHeight)
                {
                    if ((d > 0))
                    {
                        v2 =  -  computerspeed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        v2 = computerspeed;
                    }
                }
            }
            computer.y +=  v2;
            //limiting the motion of computer (it should not move beyond the stageheight)
            if (computer.y + pHalfHeight > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                computer.y = stage.stageHeight - pHalfHeight;
            }
            else if (computer.y - pHalfHeight < 0)
            {
                computer.y = 0 + pHalfHeight;
            }

            //collision with horizontal walls
            if (ball.y + bHalfHeight >= stage.stageHeight || ball.y - bHalfHeight <= 0)
            {
                vy *=  -1;
            }

            //collision with player and computer
            if (ball.x - bHalfWidth <= player.x + pHalfWidth)
            {
                if (Math.abs(ball.y - player.y) <= pHalfHeight)
                {
                    vx = ballspeed;
                    if ((v1 != 0))
                    {
                        vy = 2 * v1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ball.x + bHalfWidth >= computer.x - pHalfWidth)
            {
                if (Math.abs(ball.y - computer.y) <= pHalfHeight)
                {
                    vx =  -  ballspeed;
                    if ((v2 != 0))
                    {
                        vy = v2;
                    }
                }
            }

            //collision with vertical walls & updating scores
            if (ball.x + bHalfWidth >= stage.stageWidth)
            {
                playerScore +=  1;
                reset();
            }
            else if (ball.x - bHalfWidth <= 0)
            {
                computerScore +=  1;
                reset();
            }

            //display the score on the textfield
            //txtPlayer.text  = String(playerScore);
            //txtComputer.text = String(computerScore);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a mouse event listener to the on-screen buttons.

Comment: Look up MouseEvent.CLICK or MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN

Comment: Okay i'll give that a try and i'll get back to you on that

Comment: I've tried to incorporate it, but I have no idea where it properly goes and what other bits of code i will need to add to get it working. It's not a simple as create a mouse event and put it inside it. You would have to get rid of the keyboard events, but then other errors pop up and you would have to tell it to move up when this button is clicked wont you? I just cant get my head around it

Comment: Which mouse events you use is entirely up to the person designing the application. Do you want the "goRight" function to be called when the user hovers the cursor over the button? Clicks and releases the button? Presses and holds the button?

Comment: Basically, because this has got to be for mobile, the user holds the button down and pongUp, will make the player move up and pongDown will make the player move down. Then on release it stops. I'm assuming you would have to replace the keyboard events with the button event listeners and then tie that in with the player speed v1 is it? I'm not sure at all how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, you'll want to compile using AIR for Android or iOS. You can then replace:

```
//this function sets the velocity of player when key is pressed  
    function KeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            v1 =  -  playerspeed;
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            v1 = playerspeed;
        }
    }
    //this function sets the velocity of player to 0 if key is released 
    function KeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            v1 = 0;
        }
    }
```

with:

```
function KeyDown(event:TouchEvent):void {
    if (event.stageY < player.y){
        v1 =  -  playerspeed;
    }else if (event.stageY > player.y){
        v1 = playerspeed;
    }
}

function KeyUp(event:TouchEvent):void {
    v1 = 0;
}
```

Then replace:

```
//this function will add all event listeners
    function init(e:Event):void {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,KeyUp);
```

with:

```
//this function will add all event listeners
    function init(e:Event):void {
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, KeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, KeyUp);
```

And make sure to use TouchEvent instead of KeyboardEvent by replacing:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
```

with:

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
```

Now when you hold your finger down on the screen, the "player" will move towards that Y location. If your game is using the X axis, just change the Ys to Xs!

Hope this helps!